# what does "if { set -C; 2>/dev/null >~/test.lock; }" in a bash mean?

Tags: bash, shell

I have encountered this in a bash script:

```
if { set -C; 2>/dev/null >~/test.lock; }; then
    echo "Acquired lock"
else
    echo "Lock file exists… exiting"
    exit 1
fi
```

It enters on the else flow. I know set -C will not overwrite the files, 2>/dev/null means something as : redirect errors to "void", but then I have  >~/test.lock and will mean to redirect something in the lock file, (what exactly, the errors probably). I have test.lock the file in home, created, and empty. Being a if , it must return false in my case.

Comment: `>~/test.lock` opens `~/test.lock` for writing (nothing) but `set -C` prevents this if the file already exists. So, if the file does not exist the `if` branch is taken, while if it exists it is the `else` branch that is taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{ ... ; ... ; }` is a compound command. That is bash executes every command in it, and the exit code is the one of the last one.
It is a bit like `( ... ; ... )`, except that with `(` you execute a subshell (a bit like `sh -c "... ; ..."`) which is less efficient, and, moreover, prevent affecting local variables of your current shell, for example.

So, in short, `{ set -C; 2>/dev/null >~/test.lock; }` means "do `set -C`, then do `2>/dev/null >~/test.lock` and the return (exit code) is the one of that last command".

So `if { set -C; 2>/dev/null >~/test.lock; }` is "if `2>/dev/null >~/test.lock` succeeds in that compound command, that is after `set -C`".

Now, `set -C` means that you can't overwrite existing files

And `2>/dev/null > ~/test.lock` is an attempt to overwrite `test.lock` if it exists, or to create it if it doesn't.

So, what you have here, is

- If lock file already exist, fail and say "lock file exists, exiting"
- If lock file did not exit, create it, and say "lock acquired".

And it does it in one operation.
So it is different than

```bash
# Illustration of how NOT to do it. Do not use this code :-)
if [[ -f "test.lock" ]]
then
    echo "lock file exists, exiting"
else
    2>/dev/null > ~/test.lock
    echo "lock file acquired"
fi
```

because that, clearer but wrong, version does not guarantee that something will have created the lock file between the evaluation of the if condition and the execution of `2>/dev/null > ~/test.lock`.

The version you've shown has the advantage that the creation and test of lock is the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

`set -C` disallows writing to existing files

`2>/dev/null` suppresses warnings

`>~/test.lock` attempts to write to a file called test.lock. If the file already exists this returns an error because of `set -C`. Otherwise it will create a new `test.lock` file, making the next instance of this script fail on this step.

The purpose of lock files is to ensure that only one instance of a script runs at the same time. When the program is finished it could delete `~/test.lock` to let another instance run.